# Display Menu according to screen resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 14 menus and I want to set those menus according to screen resolution size. If screen resolution `size <= 1280px` than 8 menus will be displayed in menu bar and other menus will be displayed in `more` menu drop down. (Like in the attached screen shots)

[image: screen resolution image]

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far.

Comment: still i didn't write code for this. first i need suggest how to implement this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the menu options:

```
<ul class="flex menu">
    <li><a href="page.html">Menu Item</a></li>
    <!-- more list items... -->
</ul>
```

and initialize the menu:

```
$('ul.menu.flex').flexMenu();
```

Include the [`flexmenu.js`](https://github.com/352Media/flexMenu), here is a [demo](http://352media.github.io/flexMenu/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: Resize to make it happen

Comment: he is not asking for this kind of menu../ he wwant't to wrap the menu's under more.

Comment: many ways to resolve one problem guy. He just ask "please suggest me how to do."